# Django serializer output as part of JSON object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

### Context

I have 2 models: `Customer` & `DeviceGroup`.

Currently I have an API endpoint `/api/v1/device-groups/?customer_uuid=<customer_uuid>` which returns the `DeviceGroups` that are related to the given `Customer` like this:

```
[
    {
        "group_uuid": "c61361ac-0826-41bb-825a-8aa8e014ae0c",
        "device_group_name": "Default",
        "color": "0a2f45",
        "is_default": true
    },
    {
        "group_uuid": "1a86e8e4-b41b-4f33-aefb-ce984ef96144",
        "device_group_name": "Testgroup",
        "color": "123456",
        "is_default": false
    }
]
```

### Goal

I want the array of `DeviceGroups` be part of an object like this:

```
"device_groups": 
[
    {
        "group_uuid": "c61361ac-0826-41bb-825a-8aa8e014ae0c",
        "device_group_name": "Default",
        "color": "0a2f45",
        "is_default": true
    },
    {
        "group_uuid": "1a86e8e4-b41b-4f33-aefb-ce984ef96144",
        "device_group_name": "Testgroup",
        "color": "123456",
        "is_default": false
    }
]
```

### Models

```
# models.py

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)


class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
    group_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    customer_uuid = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    device_group_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

### Serializer

```
# serializers.py

class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ('group_uuid', 'device_group_name', 'color', 'is_default')
```

### View

```
# views.py

class DeviceGroupCustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DeviceGroupSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return DeviceGroup.objects.filter(customer_uuid=self.request.GET['customer_uuid'])
```

I tried creating a new `serializer` but it did not solve my problem:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    device_groups = DeviceGroupSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ('device_groups', 'group_uuid', 'device_group_name', 'color', 'is_default')
```

What do I need to change in order to get my desired output?

Comment: If this API just returns a list of `DeviceGroups`, I'm finding it difficult to understand why `"device_groups":` would need to be appended as an object. Do you gain anything from that?

Comment: The developer who is working with the response of the API suggested adding `"device_groups":` as an object as it would be easier for him to handle the data apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can update your views like

```
def list(self, request):
    queryset = DeviceGroup.objects.filter(customer_uuid=self.request.GET['customer_uuid'])
    serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response({'device_groups': serializer.data})
```

this will get the desired output..

Answer (score 3):

Just modify your new serializer named **TestSerializer** in the following way.

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    device_groups = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_device_groups(self, model):
        return DeviceGroupSerializer(model).data
```

The response will be a paginated response. If you want to disable it just mention pagination_class as None in your ModelViewset class.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this fairly easily without loosing the pagination, I would do this:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination 

class DeviceGroupPagination(PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('device_groups', data)
        ]))
```

Then in the views

```
class DeviceGroupCustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DeviceGroupSerializer
    pagination_class = DeviceGroupPagination
    ...
```

So now, in place of `results`, you will have `device_groups`